# How to loop though an array?

Tags: php

Hi this array contains more than one occurrences of the country how can I loop and out put all of them?

```
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=cordoba';




  $json = @file_get_contents($url);

  $jsondata = json_decode($json);
  $status = $jsondata->status;
  $address = '';
  if($status == "OK")
  {
    $address_data = $jsondata->results[0]->address_components;

    print_r( $address_data);

    //echo $address_data[3]->long_name;
  }
  else
  {
    echo "No Data Found Try Again";
  }
```

Comment: One way would be to use `foreach()` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Could you please share some code I am kind if newbie in this?

Comment: You can also read more on this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414623/loop-through-an-array-php

Comment: There are plenty of examples in the links I provided. (A suggestion, try Google before asking. It will go much faster)

Comment: OK gonna test it!

Comment: Just a side note, you're suppressing errors by appending `@` in front of your `file_get_contents()` (which means that if the URL fails, you won't get any error), but then run both the `json_encode()` and `$status = $jsondata->status` without any checks. The last one will definitely throw an error if the URL failed to start with, since it won't actually be an object..

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($address_data as $row){
         print_r($row)
}
```

Comment: It only returns one result but has to return 2 Argentina and Spain. PLease guys help me out here

Answer (score 1):

I think the one thing the rest of the answers overlooked is that your results are an array as well.

```
if($status == "OK")
{
  foreach ($jsondata->results as $result) {
    $address_data = $result->address_components;
    echo $address_data[3]->long_name;
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be `foreach ($jsondata->results as $result)`.

Comment: Awesome this works: 
 
It should be foreach ($jsondata->results as $result) How so I out put countries from this array?

Answer (score 0):

Using foreach() is the best thing you can do php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=cordoba';

$json = @file_get_contents($url);

$jsondata = json_decode($json);
$status = $jsondata->status;
$address = '';
if($status == "OK")
{
  $address_data = $jsondata->results[0]->address_components;

 foreach ($address_data as $address) {
     echo $address->long_name;
  }
}
else
{
  echo "No Data Found Try Again";
}
```

Comment: This line only returns one result: $address_data = $jsondata->results[0]->address_components; have to loop this one

Answer (score 0):

`$address_data` is actually an array of objects. Use a `foreach` loop to loop through the array and access each object's property like this:

```
// your code

foreach($address_data as $address){
    /*
    * $address->long_name
    * $address->short_name
    * $address->types[0]
    * $address->types[1]
    */
}
```