# foreach isn't working properly

Tags: php, foreach

```
<?php

$find = array('Mahmoud', 'Ahmed', 'Arafa');

if(isset($_POST['user_input']) && !empty($_POST['user_input'])){
    $user_input = $_POST['user_input'];

    for ($i=0; $i < count($user_input); $i++) { 
        //echo 'eshta';
        foreach($find as $pattern) { 
            echo "$pattern";
            if($pattern[0] == $user_input[$i]){
                $flag = 1;

                for ($k=0; $k < count($pattern); $k++) { 
                    if($pattern[$k] != $user_input[$i + $k]){
                        $flag = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if($flag){
                    for ($k=1; $k < count($pattern) - 1; $k++) { 
                        $user_input[$i + $k] = '*';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    echo $user_input;
}

?>
```

This is a snippet from my script.php for word censoring. In this line:

```
'echo "$pattern";
```

it outputs the whole array, not the current word (pattern). What's the problem?

Comment: You can loop over the array in $pattern with a for loop like how you do with the foreach.  Or you could just print the first one by using `echo $pattern[0]`.  Their isn't any problem.  Your telling it to print the whole array on every iteration, and its doing that.  Learn about fetching elements of PHP arrays.

Comment: Inside the foreach $pattern is a string not an array like you have referenced it as. Foreach working fine. It's just you understanding of it

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

URL: https://www.tehplayground.com/hlpAbDTdt4Rv617K

```
<?php

$find = array('Mahmoud', 'Ahmed', 'Arafa');

    for ($i=0; $i < count($find); $i++) { 
        //echo 'eshta';
        foreach($find as $i => $pattern) { 
            echo $find[$i];
        }
    }
?>
```

Reference: [Loop through an array php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414623/loop-through-an-array-php)