# php- How to create a loop for this code

Tags: php, loops, datetime-format

How can I use loop (for, forEach, while etc.) to the following part of code.
Here "tarray" is an array of 10 values.
The part of the code :

```
$string = $tarray[0];
$datetime = strtotime($string);
$datetime1 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $datetime);
list($year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode('-', $datetime1);

$string = $tarray[1];
$datetimea = strtotime($stringa);
$datetime2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $datetimea);
list($year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode('-', $datetime2);
```

I want to write this only once instead of declaring multiple variables.

Comment: what you want to do with this code... echo it..? Add in New array or what...Please elaborate...

Comment: Show us the loop you have tried so far and tell us what doesn't work there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414623/loop-through-an-array-php)

Comment: @GyandeepSharma I am repeating the same code again and again. So I want to convert it into a loop that will generate an array of "datetime" values

Comment: @AlivetoDie  I am repeating the same code again and again. So I want to convert it into a loop that will generate an array of "datetime" values

Comment: @user8467658  can you please check once my answer

Comment: 1. It wont work with your date format. You need to use the character '-' that you use in the explode throughout like date("Y-m-d-H-i-s", $datetimea) else your list command  will generate errors like it did when you tested it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want like this:-

```
$date_array = [];
foreach($tarray as $tar){
    $datetime1 = date("Y-m-d-H-i-s",strtotime($tar));
    $date_array[] = array_combine(['year', 'month', 'day', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'], explode('-', $datetime1));
}
```

Demo putput:- https://eval.in/897154

Note:- you can use `list($year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode('-', $datetime1);`  also there without any issue.

Demo output:-https://eval.in/897156

Comment: Thanks dude. Thats almost what I was looking for. Just tell me 'How can I print array of "datetime1"'

Comment: @user8467658 `print_r($date_array[0])`

Comment: @Alive to Die :- How can I store "$datetime1" values in "$date_array". I tried 'array_push'but it is showing as a single value.

Comment: `$date_array[] =$datetime1; `

Comment: It is generating output like: example-['value'].     But I want like : example-['value0','value1',....].   If possible can you show me demo output for "$date_array[] =$datetime1;]"

Comment: @user8467658  i am unable to get you. Either show me correct output and what you want exactly or ask a new question regarding this. You will get answer for-sure.

Comment: Can you show me a code output demo for " $date_array[]=$datetime1; "  similar to what you displayed in answer. "Demo output:-https://eval.in/897156"

Comment: @user8467658   check this:- https://eval.in/897190   . Please try to learn basics and start doing thing your own.

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach loop like that:

```
$arr = ['Hello', 'world', 'John'];
foreach($arr as $string) {
    echo $string;
}
```

So in your case:

```
foreach($tarray as $string) {
    $datetime = strtotime($string);
    $datetime1 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $datetime);
    list($year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode('-', $datetime1);
}
```