# index array results from mysql call so I can call multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Ok, so I think I should be storing my mysql query as an array since I want to call upon the data multiple times. So instead of querying the database over and over, I can just do it once and then use the array over and over.

However, I am a bit lost in how to regenerate the table I was able to with mysql+php with the new array...

Here is my array call:

```
$userid = 3;
$results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT user,product,etd FROM wp_summary WHERE user=$userid");

$history = array();
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results) ){
    $history[]= [
                  $row['product'],
                  $row['etd']
                  ];
} 
echo print_r($history); //debugging so  I can see I actually called it right
```

But what I would like to do is now dynamically generate a table with a while loop on the rows. with a MySQL query, it was like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr style='font-size: 0.8em'>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['product'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['etd'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

But I can I convert this for the array now instead of the mysql query?

Comment: Before you get too much further, have a look at sql injection, and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: @Strawberry thanks! I am just making the code easy to follow ... I have it with prepared statments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414623/loop-through-an-array-php)

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou Thank you!

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php - does your load in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own riddle after the hint from @DimitrisFilippou ;

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($history); $i++) {
    echo '<br>';
    echo $history[$i]['product'];
    echo $history[$i]['etd'];
    }
```