# Laravel : How to retrieve data from inside an nested array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to retrieve a specific column from a table in my database.
Name of the column is `verification_type_id` and table is `certificate_verification_type`.

When I `vardump()` the variable which I am using to retrieve the column, here is what I get:

```
array(2)
{
    [14]=> array(2)
    {
        ["certificate_id"]=> int(9)
        ["verification_type_id"]=> int(2)
    }
    [15]=> array(2)
    {
        ["certificate_id"]=> int(9)
        ["verification_type_id"]=> int(3)
    }
}
```

Here is my laravel eloquent query:

```
$certVeriType = CertificateVerificationType::all()->where('certificate_id', $certType)->toArray();
```

How can I only retrieve the column 'verification_type_id' form the table. Here is the migration file of the table:

```
$table->integer('certificate_id');
$table->integer('verification_type_id');
$table->index('certificate_id');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Loop it with `foreach(){}` and access the specific member which you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414623/loop-through-an-array-php)

Comment: You can use the `select()` method in your query to specify which column(s) you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add -> pluck() ( **The pluck method retrieves all of the values for a given key** ) to your eloquent query:

```
$certVeriType = CertificateVerificationType::all()
    ->where('certificate_id', $certType)
    ->pluck('verification_type_id')
    ->toArray();
```